# Analysing meaning of sentences

Tags: nlp

Are there any tools that analyze the meaning of given sentences? Recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what (spoken/written) language ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140908/parsing-meaning-from-text

Comment: "Define meaning", said the NLP researcher, and the philosophers chuckled.

Comment: what is the language and your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for similar tools. One thing I found recently was this `sentiment analysis` tool built by researchers at Stanford.

It provides a model of analyzing the sentiment of a given sentence. It's interesting and even this seemingly simple idea is quite involved to model in an accurate way. It utilizes machine learning to develop higher accuracy as well. There is a live demo where you can input sentences to analyze.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/

I also saw this `RelEx` semantic dependency relationship extractor.

http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Sentence_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Some [natural language understanding](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22natural+language+understanding%22) tools can analyze the meaning of sentences, including [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html) and [Attempto Controlled English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding). There are several implementations of [discourse representation structures](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-tpuikLvQAhXr5YMKHUfIDkcQPAgD#newwindow=1&hl=en&q=%22discourse+representation+theory%22+parser) and [semantic parsers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantic+parser%22) with a similar purpose.

There are also several parsers that can be used to generate a [meaning representation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantic+parser%22#newwindow=1&q=%22meaning+representation%22+parser) from the text that is being parsed.